# Push notification - Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have an application that executes a block of code immediately when it receives a push notification from the server. I have enabled the background modes in the application and it worked as expected in the background that is the app minimized mode. But in terminated state app receive push and calls

didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:

at the very first time. after that, if it receives another push it will not call the method.
I have working with 
**xcode: 9.1
ios: 11.2
swift: 4**

push payload

```
{
   registration_ids: to,
   data: {
     title : 'xxxxx',
     notify_id : xxxxxx,
     created_on : createdTime,
     body: body
   },
   notification: {
     title: 'xxxxxx',
     body: body,
     sound: 'xxxx.caf'
   },
   priority: 'High',
   content_available: true
 }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Because `didReceiveRemoteNotification` works for iOS 9 and below only.

Use 2 below delegates for Firebase remote push (iOS 10 and above).

**1. Receive push from background**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}
```

**2. Receive push in foreground**

```
func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {}
```

Comment: I think this will call when the user taps on the notification. My need is different. I need to get it without user interaction. Thank you.

Comment: You will know without user interaction in case you are in foreground at the moment server sends push. @Anju